# why am I getting a 'closed file' message when I run my python script?

Tags: python, file

simple bit of code, just prints out a list of urls I put into a text file (it was printing them with the \n char at the end of each one though - how do I get rid of the \n?):

```
import mechanize, fileinput

with open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt') as urls:
    content = urls.readlines()
print content
```

anyway, it worked printed out the list, great. Run it again and I get this message in the python shell:

```
<closed file 'F:\Python\url_list2.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000002E4E390>
```

What is going on? Using windows 7 x64 if that makes any difference?

Comment: It'll be easier to debug your code if you'd post it. (Guess: you're closing the file somehow, either with `close()` or a `with` statement.)

Comment: Are you sure it worked once? You're not printing out the contents, you're printing the file descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with` statement automatically closes the handle after all the statements inside it execute. If you need access to the handle afterwards:

```
import mechanize, fileinput

urls = open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt')
content = urls.readlines()
print content
```

If you want to get rid of the `\n` at the end of every line, use `.strip()`:

```
import mechanize, fileinput

urls = open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt')
content = [x.strip() for x in urls.readlines()]
print content
```

Comment: Great that the answer gives the expected output, but this leaves the file open and also renders the `strip()` list comprehension largely pointless.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: 100% agreed on the lack of `close()`; see jimbob's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983339/why-am-i-getting-a-closed-file-message-when-i-run-my-python-script/5983359#5983359) for the proper way to do this. Also, stupid typo. Thanks. (FGITW not always a good thing.)

Answer (score 3):

`with` only keeps the file open within the indentation block.  Try:

```
import mechanize, fileinput

with open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt') as urls:
    content = urls.readlines()
    print urls # file still open.
print content
```

Basically [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-812) is syntactic sugar for a common `try except finally` pattern:

```
try:
    urls = open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt')
    # rest of indented block
finally:
    urls.close()
# stuff outside of indented block
```

So your code translates into:

```
import mechanize, fileinput
try:
    urls = open('F:\Python\url_list2.txt')
    # rest of indented block
    content = urls.readlines()
finally:
    urls.close()
# stuff outside of indented block.
print urls
```

So you see why you urls is reported as a closed file ... you just closed it by exiting the `with` indentation block.  You probably want to `print content` to see the `content` you loaded into the variable from the closed `urls` file.

Comment: Don't do `except SomeException as e: raise e`. It's redundant and affects the traceback. Either `raise` without any arguments (which exists specifically to avoid that problem), or just leave the `except` clause out (you don't need one to have a `finally` clause).

Comment: @delnan: Thanks.  I wouldn't have done that in real code; off the top of my head wasn't sure if except was needed in `try - finally` (e.g., I know try w/o except (or finally) alone is syntax error).

Answer (score 2):

Try print content  (urls is gone after with closes.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to be printing `content` instead of `urls`?

To remove the newlines, use `rstrip`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `with`, this is what is actually happening:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    # do stuff
print "YAY"
# do more stuff
```

The above is equivalent to saying:

```
f = open(filepath)
try:
    # do stuff
except:
    f.close()
finally:
    f.close()
    print "YAY"
    # do more stuff
```

Does this explain why you are getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably a file object you've already called close() on? Can we see your code?

Comment: all good stuff, cheers guys (sorry there was a typo with the original post it should have been 'print content') removed the with and it's all ok now thanks